# static library armv7 not working on iOS 9

Tags: ios, xcode, armv7, arm64

I am working on a iOS app that uses a commercial static library (.a) which is compiled for armv7 architecture. This works fine but it does not work on iOS 9 because Apple requires that all libs should support arm64. 
Until now the vendor of this library will not deliver me a arm64 version of this library.

I've googled this a lot lately but cannot find a solution or workaround to make this work.
Many posts also on stackoverflow say this will not work.
I've tried, as some posts say, to add -Wl,-segalign,4000 to the other linker flags in the build settings of XCode in the target of my project but it did not work.

So this probably will not work, but I was wondering does anyone know a solution/workaround so that my app with this static library will work on iOS 9?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: From my experience you need the source code of the static library in order to compile for arm64.

Comment: See the many, many, duplicates of this question where everybody repeatedly says "no, there is no other way, you need a 64-bit version of the library to link against 64-bit code".

Comment: Ok thanks for your anwsers.

Answer (score 0):

As you have ascertained there is no solution here other than obtaining a 64-bit library from the vendor. I am in the same boat with an internal application I own that leverages a vendor's (antiquated) framework that is based on armv7. Until you get your hands on a 64-bit version of that library you are dead in the water.